# How to get back original query from AST generated from pglast package

Tags: python, postgresql

I am using pglast to create abstract syntax tree (AST) of queries. e.g.

```
from pglast import parse_sql
parse_sql("SELECT name, age FROM user as a WHERE age > 18;")
```

will give me

```
(<RawStmt stmt=<SelectStmt targetList=(<ResTarget val=<ColumnRef fields=(<String sval='name'>,)>>, <ResTarget val=<ColumnRef fields=(<String sval='age'>,)>>) fromClause=(<RangeFunction lateral=False ordinality=False is_rowsfrom=False functions=((<SQLValueFunction op=<SQLValueFunctionOp.SVFOP_USER: 11> typmod=-1>, None),) alias=<Alias aliasname='a'>>,) whereClause=<A_Expr kind=<A_Expr_Kind.AEXPR_OP: 0> name=(<String sval='>'>,) lexpr=<ColumnRef fields=(<String sval='age'>,)> rexpr=<A_Const isnull=False val=<Integer ival=18>>> groupDistinct=False limitOption=<LimitOption.LIMIT_OPTION_DEFAULT: 0> op=<SetOperation.SETOP_NONE: 0> all=False> stmt_location=0 stmt_len=46>,)
```

I also need to get back to original query from this output. How it can be done?

There is another function in the package (`parser.parse_sql_json`) which generate AST in json version but has added information of location of words in the query. Will output of this be easier to get back original query

```
from pglast.parser import parse_sql_json
parse_sql_json('SELECT name, age FROM user as a WHERE age > 18;')
```

gives me

```
'{"version":150001,"stmts":[{"stmt":{"SelectStmt":{"targetList":[{"ResTarget":{"val":{"ColumnRef":{"fields":[{"String":{"sval":"name"}}],"location":7}},"location":7}},{"ResTarget":{"val":{"ColumnRef":{"fields":[{"String":{"sval":"age"}}],"location":13}},"location":13}}],"fromClause":[{"RangeFunction":{"functions":[{"List":{"items":[{"SQLValueFunction":{"op":"SVFOP_USER","typmod":-1,"location":22}},{}]}}],"alias":{"aliasname":"a"}}}],"whereClause":{"A_Expr":{"kind":"AEXPR_OP","name":[{"String":{"sval":"\\u003e"}}],"lexpr":{"ColumnRef":{"fields":[{"String":{"sval":"age"}}],"location":38}},"rexpr":{"A_Const":{"ival":{"ival":18},"location":44}},"location":42}},"limitOption":"LIMIT_OPTION_DEFAULT","op":"SETOP_NONE"}},"stmt_len":46}]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `stream` module:

```
from pglast.parser import parse_sql
ast = parse_sql('select name, age from user as a where age > 18;')

from pglast.stream import RawStream
print(RawStream()(ast[0].stmt))
```

Output:

```
SELECT name, age FROM USER AS a WHERE age > 18
```

Note the keywords have been normalized to upper case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Node` objects and their properties to navigate the AST and build the query string to recreate the original query from the AST produced by `pglast`. This method guarantees an accurate reconstruction of the original query and makes it simple to manipulate its components for additional analysis or processing. Similarly, the query string can be built using the `Node` objects and properties and the json version of the AST produced by `parser.parse_sql_json`.

Comment: This is more appropriate for a comment than an answer. An answer should include instructions.